What are the supply duties of the government for mandatory schooling?
I'm mostly interested in the German jurisdiction but other countries are interesting as well. For all children attending school is mandatory, in Germany this is regulated by states (here is an example from the state of Berlin (in German)). But as far as I can see all this regulates are the duties of the children and their parents. At what age does the mandatory schooling start, for how long does it last, what parts of the school activities are covered. It does not seem to regulate in any way what the schools have to offer.
The first aspect is that any child covered by mandatory schooling should be offered a spot in some suitable school. The second aspect that I'm most interested in, is how much teaching the school has to offer? How many class hours per week are offered? For which reasons (emergencies) and for how long can schooling be suspended? Do the children also have a right (against the state) to be taught in school?
The Berlin school law contains a provision that teaching happens regularly 5 days per week but as I see it there is nothing in there preventing the state to announce for example 'due to budget constraints schooling will be reduced to 1 hour per day' or 'due to a major construction project the school will be closed for 3 months'. What are regulations on how much schooling has to be provided?

Are you interested in the states obligations or the schools? States regulate very closely what, how and when is taught in schools... but they are the ones that make those regulations, with a sufficient majority, they could obviously change them to something stupid like 3 hours of dancing your name per day. That is a political question.

In the "Bundesnotbremse II" decision of the BVerfG (2021) the court found a "right to school education" in the constitution. It set borders for closing schools due to a pandemic. English press release and decision, German decision

@K-HB The gist of this seems to be similar to o.m. answer, the state has a duty to provide a minimal standard as long as such provision is within their means.

There was a case in Thuringia where students tried to sue their school (4 EO 614/22) to get all the lessons which their school was supposed to teach. This failed. While the case the students claimed was specialized (a bilingual school), the reasoning from para. 38 onwards is more general.

That was exactly the kind of argument I was looking for. So it seems it is sufficient if the schools/ states 'try their best within their means' and there are no specifics how many classes that should actually entail.

Para 3 says basically "You have no recourse from reduced schooling based on the law in Thuringia."

What schools teach is regulated by laws. They might differ from federal state to federal state, for example in Berlin:
Schulgesetz für das Land Berlin (Schulgesetz - SchulG)
That is a lot more than I can quote here.
If you drill down into the details enough, you will find that each federal state has "Lehrpläne", "Kerncurricula" or "Rahmenlehrpläne". Basically plans and guidelines on what has to be taught when and how.
There are hundreds of those per state, basically at least one per school level and school subject. So again, sorry, too much material to quote. They are publicly available though if you are interested.
For example for Berlin/Brandenburg:
Rahmenlehrpläne Berlin
All of these are laws and regulations and output of commissions discussing them. There can be political decisions to change them. Apart from protest by parents, public ridicule, bad press and certain loss of the majority in the next election, there is little stopping a party having a majority to change them to their liking, even to something stupid. But then it is buerocratic to the extreme, so any radical change will probably get stuck and vaguely linger around for years until nobody remembers it anymore and majorities have shifted anyway.

The plans and guidelines seem to explain in great detail what the content of the classes should be and what the students are supposed to learn. But I don't see anything about the schools having to actually provide teaching. They only need to ensure that the kids learn the stuff. Something provision like 'in grades 1 to 4 there should be 3 hours of maths per week' seems to be completely absent.

Massive Error on the curricula:  It's one Rahmenlehrplan per school subject and school level (e.g. Deutsch für Grundschule, Mathematik für Weiterführende Schulen), and those contain sub-spreadsheets per class and those contain the topics. Those in turn are based on the results and discussions of the KMK - conference of ministries of culture [&education]

Can you elaborate on the "massive error"? To me, the KMK and their results is what I described as "output of commissions discussing them". "Topic" might be a really bad translation of "Fach" though, I will try to find a better one.

It was class and topic that was the critical error - it implied there is a curriculum just for Faust I in class 11 and one for the same book in class 12. But as corrected, each Fach (subject) has one per school level (Bildundsstufe), containing topics (themen) for each class (klasse)

"even to something stupid" We have state governments in the US prohibiting teaching the truth about slavery, the Civil War, LGBTQ+ issues, etc. This would be akin to a German state not teaching about the Holocaust.
